Interpreting Inter-factor Correlation Matrix
Informed by theory (i.e. assuming the factor are correlated), I ran oblique rotations for an EFA on four factors. The factor correlations I get range from 0.10 to 0.59. I used the psych::fa() function in R.
I am not sure how to interpret these, as in, are these correlations statistically significant?
Is there a way to find out the associated p-value with each of the factor correlations?

There is not enough information in this Q  for an answer, please, add context, sample size, etc ... Please do so as an edit to th Q, not only as comments, as comments on this site are ephemeral, often seen by very few, and can be deleted!
